# Thinking Sphinx without condition on 'id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

According to the documentation on [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#conditions) it should be possible to add a filter condition on id, but the following code does not give any results:

`User.search(:without => {:id => [1,3]})`

What am I doing wrong?
Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to define an index as follows:

```
define_index do
  has user(:id)
end
```

Comment: This helped me as well. In my case I had to use 'pubs(:id)' so I guess you have to look at the plural if it doesn't work for you on the first try.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use ActiveRecord for this simple query?

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => ["id NOT IN (?)", [1, 3]])
```

Comment: That's indeed what I will, but this condition is part of a whole bunch of search conditions and it is so much easier with sphinx.